# What kind of materials are plastic syringes made from?

Tags: materials, biomedical-engineering

I'm trying to figure out what kind of materials my disposable plastic syringe is made from. I have a [Medefil MIS-1130](http://medefilinc.com/saline-iv-flush-syringes-.html) syringe and when I visited the company website I couldn't find any information on what the disposable syringes were made from (although they did tell me a lot on what's NOT in them).

I'm trying to find a regulation or something that could help me identify what kind of plastic and rubber are used to make the shill, plunger and seal that make up the disposable syringe. Can anyone on here please give me some guidance?

Comment: Most of the ones I have seen have the milky look of HDPE. How specific do you need to be?

Comment: I'm actually just looking for what kind of "Special Controls" are placed on "Piston Syringes" since that's what this is. I know that they fall under the FDA Class 2 regulations which means it must follow both general and special controls but I can't find what these controls are.